# Spinning observer inside a solenoid paradox?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, relative-motion

It is well known that magnetic fields are frame dependent, with an observer travelling parallel to a moving point charge experiencing no field.

Similarly for a solenoid, a stationary observer on the central axis will experience zero field if the solenoid rotates at .99c or so and translates at the correct "screw speed" for the solenoid winding.

So far so good....

Now by equivalence, imagine a stationary solenoid with a rotating observer translating the central axis at the screw speed (which importantly can with sufficiently narrow winding be quite slow (<.001c) and completely non-relativistic).

Paradox 1

Will such an observer experience no field irrespective of the DC current in the solenoid, including zero and varying currents ?

It would seem so!

Paradox 2

Imagine a plasma surrounding the solenoid and nominally stationary wrt solenoid reference frame.

How does the spinning observer interpret the highly dynamic response, including induced fields, of the plasma to a wildly varying solenoid magnetic field that the observer continuously measures as zero ?

Comment: I think if you look up the Lorentz transformation for the four vector current you will find you cannot rotate a solenoid at 0.99c and not see an effect.  That just seems wrong to me because rotations are not inertial, so you'd need to do an infinite number of Lorentz transformations for each point along the wire to even handle such a problem dynamically.  Perhaps I am missing something, but I think there's an issue with the assumptions here...

Comment: The solenoid rotation is irrelevant, it is just setting up the equivalence of the spinning observer which is very clearly non-relativistic v<<0.001c.

Comment: The current flows at least partially along the rotation, so it's not irrelevant.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is just preamble and could be deleted. What is your point with that paragraph deleted ?

Comment: What is the "screw speed"?  If I assume the solenoid is not rotating but only the observer is within the solenoid, then the observer will see both a magnetic and electric field (the latter because they are moving relative to a stationary magnetic field).